# AWS SSL configuration with Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to search any relevant step by step guidance for implementing Amazon SSL with my Ubuntu Server on EC2 instance but haven't got any of desired help.

I would highly appreciate step by step configuration of ubuntu server with Apache2 to incorporate with Amazon SSL and make HTTPS work on my server.

I have done the steps with OpenSSL but everytime get Non-secure connection.

I have also opened the ports which are under inbound rules in Amazon console but still non-secure.

Comment: My issue is resolved.